# How to get modified column in this app script function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I had a function working qute well but I can not modify something. I need this cell to add new values once I select a new option in the drop down. This only for the 9th and 11th columns, but is not working well.

```js
function onEdit(e){
  addValue(e);
}

function addValue(e) {

  // Vairables
  var ws = "HR Support";
  var identifiedBy = 9;
  var impDimension = 11;

  // Get modified column
  var col = e.range.getColumn();

  if( col === identifiedBy || col === impDimension || e.oldValue == null || e.value == null 
  && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === ws) return;
  e.range.setValue(e.oldValue+", "+e.value);

}
```

[image: sheet]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I probably need a little more information but this does something close what I think you're looking for.  Let me know what else you need.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast('entry');
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "HR Support" && (e.range.columnStart == 9 || e.range.columnStart == 11) && e.range.rowStart > 2) {
    //e.source.toast('cond');
    e.range.setValue(e.oldValue + ", " + e.value);
  }
}
```

I think maybe you want this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast('entry');
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  sh.getRange('A1').setValue(JSON.stringify(e));
  if (sh.getName() == "HR Support" && (e.range.columnStart == 9 || e.range.columnStart == 11) && e.range.rowStart > 2) {
    e.source.toast('cond');
    if (!e.hasOwnProperty('oldValue')) {//checks to see if oldValue is a property of event object
      e.range.setValue(e.value);
    } else {
      e.range.setValue(e.oldValue + ", " + e.value);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi! thank you for your response. Unfortunately, it isn't working. What I am needing is, once I choose an option in the dropdown, then it will be added on my cell. So for example, if I have 3 optiones in the drop down: "A, B, C" and first I choose A, and then B,  then in my cell will be shown "A,C"  I hope I am clear! thanks

Comment: Please reread your comment.  You say  if your selection are a,b,c and you choose a and then b that you cell will contain a,c .  And prior to that you say once you chose an option that it will be added on you cell.   The two statements don't agree.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake, you are right. I choose A, then B, so will be shown "A,B". That is what I am needing.

Comment: The that is exactly what the second version does and it no longer displays "undefined" when `e.hasOwnProperty('oldValue')` is  false.  Of course one of the problems with what you are doing is that your spreadsheet will always display an error because your putting in a value which is not in it's current list.

Comment: Hi! it seems to be working quite well!  Anyway, when I delete only 1 cell, the undefined value appears. If I delete several cells, it does not appear.

Comment: What are you deleting?  You never talked about delete in columns 9 or 11.  You have to learn how to debug these things on your own.  You're the only person that has your data.  We don't have and in my I won't follow links into your spreadsheet.  Some volunteers do but I don't.

Comment: Yes, for example if I delete a column then an undefined  value appears. As it's a spreadsheet, deleting is a regular operation on it.

Comment: Then you need to realize that column 9 becomes colum8 if you delete column2 this making your onEdit no longer usable.  Thus all the more reason for you to learn how write the code yourself.

Comment: I personally use spreadsheet to hold data and some controls and I think them through carefully so I minimize future changes but when when changes occur then I'm prepared to deal with them.  If things are going to change then I will often deploy a row usually the top row that tells me what the column is so that if a change occurs I can keep the software going because I don't rely on column numbers.  And if people mess with my top row I just don't fix it anymore.  I let them fix it.